# Install into system instead of local directory?

Tags: julia, jupyter, ipython, ijulia-notebook, jupyter-kernel

```
julia> using Pkg

julia> Pkg.add("IJulia")
  Installing known registries into `~/.julia`
  ...
```

By default:

- Installs known registries into `~/.julia`
- Install kernel into `~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/julia-1.8`

Is it possible to do a system install instead of local install? e.g.

- `/usr/.julia`
- `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/julia-1.8`

I know specifying kernel path is possible from the Jupyter side:
https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernels.html#kernel-specs

But not sure if or how you can invoke this behavior from the julia shell
https://julialang.github.io/IJulia.jl/stable/manual/installation/

Using Linux OS

Answer (score 0):

IJulia.jl installs kernels using the `JUPYTER_DATA_DIR` environment variable. This can be set via your shell, or in Julia as

```
ENV["JUPYTER_DATA_DIR"] = "/usr/local/share/jupyter/"
```

(see https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/blob/master/deps/kspec.jl)
You can be even more fine-grained at the level of `installkernel`: see [IJulia.installkernel](https://julialang.github.io/IJulia.jl/dev/library/public/#IJulia.installkernel)

Where the `.julia` directory is located is an entirely different question, and is controlled by the `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` environment variable: see
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/environment-variables/#JULIA_DEPOT_PATH

This in turn is used to define `Base.DEPOT_PATH` which can be called in the Julia REPL to see its value.